# Add a comma to every column value in a table [unix]

Tags: awk

I have a file produced from a program that is filled with values as such :

```
1 [4:space] 2 [4:space] 3 [4:space] ... N
```

There is 4 space between each values, I want to remove the 3 spaces and place commas after each values to get the final results :

```
1, 2, 3, ..., N
```

I found out from other topics that this command can remove the 3 spaces :

```
awk -F'  +' -v OFS='\t' '{sub(/ +$/,""); $1=$1}1' file
```

I need to add commas then, or maybe is there a way to removes the space and add commas at the same time.

Comment: Puting `[unix]` at the end of your subject line makes it look at a glance like it's `[closed]` to us looking through the lists of questions. I bypassed this first couple of times looking through the list of new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace all space with comma and a space, use:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/ +/,", ")}1' file
1, 2, 3, ..., N
```

To replace exactly three spaces with a comma, use:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/ {3}/,",")}1' file
```

Using field delimiters for it:

```
$ awk -F"    " -v OFS=", " '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Comment: thanks that was what i was looking for, besides do you know how to add a bracket before the first value and after last value to get the results :

[1, 2, 3, ..., N]

Comment: Add these in the end of the code block. `$1="[" $1;$NF=$NF "]"`, ie. for example: `awk '{gsub(/ +/,", ");$1="[" $1;$NF=$NF "]"}1'` (If you have Windows line endings (`\r\n`) , you need to deal with those first using `sub(/\r$/,"")`.)

Comment: When i do this it creates me 3 lines inside my exit file. Here's my script overall. I converted my initial file into one line with tr command, then awk. 

tr '\n' ' ' < $1 | awk '{gsub(/ {3}/,",")}1;$1="[" $1;$NF=$NF "]"' > test_script

First line fill the commas, and the 2 others are duplicated with the [ and the end and beginning of line.

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/ {3}/,",");$1="[" $1;$NF=$NF "]"}1'` Please, post the original file before the `tr`, I believe it can be converted using awk only.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, and last question to annoy with. How do you remove the last comma, or more precisely erase the last comma with the final bracket ].

Comment: My original file is nothing more than a table of MxN values. My script consists to convert the table in one line with commas and bracket so that i can work with in Python

Comment: Ok i found out i placed '{gsub(/,$/,"");' to remove last comma. my full script is now :

tr '\n' ' ' < $1 | awk '{gsub(/ {3}/,",");$1="[" $1;{gsub(/,$/,"")};$NF=$NF "]"}1' > test_script

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/ {3}/,",");$1="[" $1;sub(/,$/,"]")}1'`

Comment: @haswellrefresh never do `tr '\n' anything | any text processing tool` as removing the newlines makes the output no longer a valid text file and then what any text processing tool does with it is undefined behavior. `I converted my initial file into one line with tr command` is just never the right approach. Post a new question with your original text file if you'd like help doing whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed to modify file in place:

```
sed -i -e 's/    /, /g' file
```

And with the brackets:

```
sed -i -e 's/    /, /g;s/^/[/;s/$/]/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

how about hands-free driving with `awk`?

```
{m,n,g}awk NF=NF RS='\r?\n' OFS=', '
```

It'll handle both `CRLF` from `windows` and `unix` `LF`, trim both ends,and place `", "` in between each field